# "text/stream" streams text when request is sent to VM's IP but when I send the same request to the domain, it sends the complete response as one

Tags: nginx, networking, dns, backend, streaming

I have a cloud VM where I'm running my backend. I have an endpoint which returns a text/stream type. I have 2 domains pointing towards the VM's IP and NGINX configured. When I send a request to the VM's IP I get a streaming response as expected but the same request when sent to the domain returns the entire message in one chunk.

I expected to get a streaming response but i get the entire response at one.